# Inject code automatically to a python project and execute

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to inject some code to all python modules in my project automatically.
I used [ast.NodeTransformer](https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manipulating.html#modifying-the-tree) and managed to change it quite easily, the problem is that I want to run the project.

An ast node is per module and I want to change all modules in the project and then run; and I have this [example](https://bitbucket.org/takluyver/greentreesnakes/src/master/examples/wrap_integers.py)

The problem is that it applies to one node, viz. one file. I want to run this file, which imports and uses other files which I want to change too, so I'm not sure how to get it done.

I know I can use some ast-to-code module, like astor, but all are third party and I don't want to deal with bugs and unexpected issues.

Don't really know how to start, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> I know I can use some ast-to-code module, like astor, but all are third party and I don't want to deal with bugs and unexpected issues.

From 3.9 onward there is ast.unparse, which practically does AST to source conversion after you transform it.